# Шахматная доска, по книге "Выразительный JavaScript"

Tags: javascript

Условия самой задачи. Единственное что у меня не получается, это сделать через одну строку крайний левый пробел.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
for (var i = '# # # #'; i.length < 17; i = i + ' ') {
    document.write(i + '<br>');
    console.log("["+i+"]");    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если длина строки `i` нечетная, то ставится пробел:

```js
for (var i = '# # # #'; i.length < 17; i = i + ' ') {
  document.write(i + '<br>' + ((i.length % 2 == 1) ? '&nbsp' : ''));
}
//console.log("["+i+"]");
```

Comment: ? ' &nbsp' : '' - поскольку я в этом деле новичек, можешь объяснить что вот эта часть строки делает после вопросительного знака

Comment: ? - оператор условия, который выбирает одно из двух; 
&nbsp - знак пробела

Answer (score 2):

```js
var inside = "[&nbsp;&nbsp;][#][&nbsp;&nbsp;][#][&nbsp;&nbsp;][#][&nbsp;&nbsp;]";
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var head = (i % 2 != 0)? "" : "[#]";
  var tail = (i % 2 == 0)? "" : "[#]";
  var line = head + inside + tail;
  document.write(line + '<br>');
  //console.log("["+line+"]");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let line = "";
let size = 8;
let letter1 = "#";
let letter2 = " ";
for (count = 0; count < (size * (size + 1)); count++) {
  if (count % (size + 1) == 0) {
    line = line + '\n';
  } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
    line = line + letter1;
  } else {
    line = line + letter2;
  }
}
console.log(line);
```

Программа работает корректно для решетки ***8х8***, а так же для любой другой решетки с четной стороной ***6х6, 12х12 и т.п.***.

Для нечетных сторон корректно программу допилить пока не смог.